# mysql get result from dynamicly formated column name

Tags: mysql

I have to get result from column which name is generated by the data from another column. I will explain with the following example:

column names in the database:

months | am1 | am2 | am3 | am4 | am5 | am6 | am7 | am8 | am9 | am10 |am11 | am12

[image]

I want in my query to get the value from column starting with `am` + months value
my current query is:

```
$query = 'select id, iid, contractnumber, concat("am",`months`) as amount from credits where iid > 0';
```

but this instead of returning the value (71) of the specific `am..` column it returns the column name, for example `am5`

How can I directly access the value of column `am5`

Thank you for your time !

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here :-(

Comment: Care to fix your design? As it is right now, you should just run two queries. First get the value from `months`. Then compose the column name in your application language for the second query. But I already hear someone typing in a huge and ugly CASE statement as answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bad design and you should change it, but if that's what you got, you can use `CASE`

```
select id, iid, contractnumber,
  case months
  when 1 then am1
  when 2 then am2
  when 3 then am3
  when 4 then am4
  when 5 then am5
  when 6 then am6
  when 7 then am7
  when 8 then am8
  when 9 then am9
  when 10 then am10
  when 11 then am11
  when 12 then am12
  end as amount
from credits 
where iid > 0
```

Comment: Thank you slaakso, its working exept double select at the beginning, What table design would better works? If you have to save amount for each month in the table..

Comment: Put the months into a separate table. Not sure what the logic of the table is, so cannot be more specific.